# How can I have both Smarty and HTML auto-indentation?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, smarty, syntax-highlighting

I use Smarty with HTML in Visual Studio Code. I would like to have both Smarty and HTML syntax highlighted and properly indented. HTML works by default (highlight, indentation, and autocompletion). I tried to install the Smarty Template Support extension and now both HTML and Smarty are highlighted, but only Smarty is indented properly, not HTML.

Can I have both somehow?

P.S. To enable Smarty in html files I've added to `settings.json`:

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.html": "smarty",
        "*.htm": "smarty"
},
```

Comment: Only one formatting extension can work at a time, and this Smarty extension has issues with indentation: https://github.com/aswinkumar863/smarty-vscode-support/issues/303, https://github.com/aswinkumar863/smarty-vscode-support/issues/193. I think you will have to wait for them to fix the issues or find a different extension.

Comment: @PatrickStephansen, I tried another top extension "Smarty v0.3.0 by imperez", and it has the exact same issue.